# Запятая при двойном сочинительном союзе в примере

Tags: союзы

Требуется ли постановка запятой в следующем примере:

Что ж, мы и в пятницу, и в субботу играем?

Answer (score 3):

Как мне кажется, лучше так записать (если это уточнение):

***Так что** (получается), мы и в пятницу, и в субботу играем?*

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, запятая не требуется: фраза вполне подходит под правило о *смысловом единстве.*

> 2. При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом ***и***, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное **смысловое единство** (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов): *Кругом было **и светло и зелено*** (Тургенев); *Он носил **и лето и зиму** старую жокейскую кепку* (Паустовский) (...) Такие смысловые единства образуются словами с ассоциативными (часто антонимическими) связями:
>
> *и блюдца и чашки*
>
> *и брат и сестра*
>
> *и глухой и немой*
>
> *и друзья и враги*
>
> *и зимой и летом*
>
> (...)
>
> http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

Comment: А  какие могут быть ассоциативные связи  между пятницей и субботой?  И кстати, повторяющийся предлог В их взаимной близости никак не мешает? А вот у Розенталя нет таких примеров (чтобы с предлогами).

Comment: «А какие могут быть ассоциативные связи между пятницей и субботой?» — а самой подумать? :) «И кстати, повторяющийся предлог В их взаимной близости никак не мешает?» — нисколько. «А вот у Розенталя нет таких примеров (чтобы с предлогами)» — нет и указания, что повторяющиеся предлоги как-то мешают единству.